# Understanding definition of derivative of a scalar field

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a scalar field i.e., $f:S\subseteq\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is defined on a set $S\subseteq \mathbb R^n$. Let $B(a,r)=\{x\in S:\|x-a\|\lt r\}$ be an $n$-ball inside $S$. **Let $v\in S$ be a vector such that $\|v\|\lt r$**, so that $a+v\in B(a,r)$.

Then, $f$ is said to be differentiable at $a$ if $\exists$ a linear transformation $T_a:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ and a scalar function $E(a,v)$ such that :
$f(a+v)-f(a)=T_a(v)+\|v\|E(a,r)$ and $E(a,r)\to 0$ as $\|v\|\to 0$ .
The linear transformation $T_a$ is called total derivative of $f$ at $a$.

**What I don't understand is why does it have to be**  $\mathbf{\|v\|\lt r}$ in "Let $v\in S$ be a vector such that $\mathbf{\|v\|\lt r}$"?

$a+v\in B(a,v)$ **is understandable as we want to define** $f(a+v)$ **but how does** $\|v\|\lt r$ **guarantee that** $a+v\in B(a,r)$?

**Does** $S$ **have to contain** $0$ **vector so that we can take the limit** $\|v\|\to 0$?

Please guide. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $B(a,r) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x-a\| < r \},$ i.e. $x \in B(a,r)$ iff $\|x-a\| < r.$

If $\|v\|<r$ then
$\|(a+v)-a\| = \|v\| < r$
so $a+v \in B(a,r).$

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot.